# jQuery override older version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, overriding

We have reference to jQuery 1.3.2 in the head of a page which we can't change, and further down the page it calls jQuery 1.5.1.

Will it just override itself in the code further down or can there be potential conflicts?

Comment: did you got the conflicts or any error???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will probably need to use the noConflict command:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

If you aren't actually using the older version at all I would put this at the top directly after it is loaded (but before you load 1.5.1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict(true); // <-- true removes the reference to jQuery aswell.
</script>
```